# ListView.builder inside ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have some problem.I try to write listview.builder in listView.But my page is not scrolling.When i tap widgets(green background) - page is scrolling.When i tap widgets(yellow background) - page is not
scrolling.I am trying to fix.But haven't decided yet.

```
 Scaffold(

  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      // Widgets  ... //green background
      

        child: ListView.builder( //yellow background
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           
            ListView.builder(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index){return Container()}
           },
          
        ),
     
    ],
  ),

)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView.builder(
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
)